# On implementation of base64 decode in coreutil

Tags: c, linux, gnu-coreutils

Recently I'm starting to read the source of coreutil(version 8.23, source: git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils)

when reading base64.c(which implements encoding and decoding algorithm for base64), I found the decoding implementation is a bit strange when with -i option (i.e ignore non base64 characters)

Here is code([src/base64.c line222 ~ 232](http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/base64.c#213))

```
sum = 0
n = fread (inbuf + sum, 1, DEC_B64BLOCKSIZE - sum, in);
if (ignore_garbage)
{   
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; n > 0 && i < n;) 
        if (isbase64 (inbuf[sum + i]) || inbuf[sum + i] == '=')
            i++;
        else
            memmove (inbuf + sum + i, inbuf + sum + i + 1, --n - i); 
 }
```

when `ignore_garbage` is set, whenever a non-base64 char is found, a memmove operation is done. i.e move all the left chars to current position.

so, if there are N non-base64 chars, N times of memmove will be taken. which I think is very inefficient.

Instead, why we just simply do a completely scan on inbuf, find all non-base64 chars, and fill inbuf with all left chars?

Is there any limitations for this implementation? Thank you for any suggestion.

```
sum = 0;
n = fread(inbuf+sum, 1, DEC_B64BLOCKSIZE-sum, in);

if (ignore_garbage)
{
    size_t i, j = 0;
    for (i=0; n>0 && i< n;i++)
    {
        if (isbase64(inbuf[sum+i]) || inbuf[sum+i] == '='){
            inbuf[sum + j] = inbuf[sum + i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    // after the loop, inbuf+sum will contain next j valid chars
}
```

Comment: That's the algorithm I'd used.  I suspect the close votes are because this is more of a [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question than a Stack Overflow question.  At the least, you've not identified the problem that you need solving.